# User defined literals for variadic char template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Recently, in the gcc-trunk sources was implemented the "user defined literals".
Tell me please, do I understand correctly that I can`t define a "user defined literals" for variadic char template?

```
template<char... chars>
int operator"" _call() { return sizeof...(chars); }
...
std::cout << "method"_call;
```

**Up.**

I don`t understand why this expression is allowed:

```
template<char... chars>
int operator"" _call() { return sizeof...(chars); }
...
std::cout << 12345566_call;
```

and this one is disallowed:

```
template<char... chars>
int operator"" _call() { return sizeof...(chars); }
...
std::cout << method_call;
```

?

What's the point?

**Up.**
this is because of the ambiguity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method_call` is a valid identifier As is for example `some_call` or `my_call`. Now imagine how much code would be broken if such identifiers were allowed to be redefined by `operator""`.

Answer (score 8):

No, it doesn't really make sense. String literals are passed as two arguments to `operator""`, and one of them is size, so what you want is:

```
size_t operator"" _call(const char*, size_t len) {
    return len;
}
```

Standard quote time (2.14.8.5):

> 5 If L is a *user-deﬁned-string-literal*, let *str* be the literal without its *ud-suffix* and let *len* be the number of code units in *str* (i.e., its length excluding the terminating null character). The literal L is treated as a call of the form
>
> ```
> operator "" X (str, len)
> ```

The variadic template forms are considered only for *user-deﬁned-integer-literal* (2.14.8.3) and *user-deﬁned-floating-literal* (2.14.8.4).

As for `method_call`, `method` is not a literal.

Comment: I know about this variant. But I expected variadic char template.

Comment: @niXman: It's not a "variant". That's how it is defined by the standard. Only user-defined integral and floating point literals allow you to use `template <char...>` form (so `12_call` would work in your first snippet).