# User defined literals definitions

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I was taking a look at the [cppreference page for user defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) literals, and I think I understand everything except a few examples

```
template <char...> double operator "" _π(); // OK
```

How does this operator work?  How can you call it?

```
double operator"" _Z(long double); // error: all names that begin with underscore
                                   // followed by uppercase letter are reserved
double operator""_Z(long double); // OK: even though _Z is reserved ""_Z is allowed
```

What is the difference between the above two functions?  What would be the difference in calling the first function as opposed to the second  if the first were not an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> template <char...> double operator "" _π(); // OK
> ```
>
> How does this operator work? How can you call it?

`1.234_π` will call `operator "" _π<'1', '.', '2', '3', '4'>()`. This form allows you to detect differences in spelling that would ordinarily be undetectable (`1.2` vs `1.20`, for example), and allows you to avoid rounding issues due to `1.2` not being exactly representable in even `long double`.

> ```
> double operator"" _Z(long double); // error: all names that begin with underscore
>                                    // followed by uppercase letter are reserved
> double operator""_Z(long double); // OK: even though _Z is reserved ""_Z is allowed
> ```
>
> What is the difference between the above two functions?

The C++ standard defines the grammar in terms of *tokens*, which you can sort of interpret as words. `"" _Z` is two tokens, `""` and `_Z`. `""_Z` is a single token.

This distinction matters: given `#define S " world!"`, and then `"Hello" S`, the whitespace is what makes `S` a standalone token, preventing it from being seen as a user-defined literal suffix.

For easier coding, both `"" _Z` and `""_Z` syntaxes are generally allowed when defining these functions, but the `"" _Z` syntax requires `_Z` to be seen as an identifier. This can cause problems when an implementation predefines `_Z` as a macro, or declares it as a custom keyword.

Comment: Do you know why with the `_π` literal, something like this `"something"_π` does not call `operator "" _π<'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g'>()`?  How can i change the declaration of that user defined literal to make those characters be passed as template arguments?

Comment: @Curious That's not possible, passing the individual characters as template arguments is only possible with numeric literals.

Comment: any idea why thats so?  I don't understand why characters would not be supported as well..

Comment: @Curious I'm guessing simply because with numeric literals, concrete examples were found where the template form helped, and with string and character literals, not so.

Comment: It just seems like you have to go out of your way and not support regular string literals.. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Curious To be clear, string literals with user-defined suffixes are supported. It's only that you can't use function templates for those, you have to use regular functions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand there is not difference between the two signitures.

The issue is that the identifier `_Z` is technically reserved by the standard. The main difference is that there is a space:

```
double operator""/*space*/_Z(long double); 

double operator""_Z(long double);
```

Removing the space is basically a workaround that in theory would suppress the error (or more likely a warning).

As far as how you use them, did you look at the examples from the link you listed?

```
#include <iostream>

// used as conversion
constexpr long double operator"" _deg ( long double deg )
{
    return deg*3.141592/180;
}

// used with custom type
struct mytype
{
    mytype ( unsigned long long m):m(m){}
    unsigned long long m;
};
mytype operator"" _mytype ( unsigned long long n )
{
    return mytype(n);
}

// used for side-effects
void operator"" _print ( const char* str )
{
    std::cout << str;
}

int main(){
    double x = 90.0_deg;
    std::cout << std::fixed << x << '\n';
    mytype y = 123_mytype;
    std::cout << y.m << '\n';
    0x123ABC_print;
}
```

The idea behind the user defined literals is to allow the creation of an operator that can be applied to built in types that can convert the built in literal to another type.

EDIT:

To call one of these operators you just need to append the operator as a suffix to a value literal. So given:

```
// used as conversion
constexpr long double operator"" _deg ( long double deg )
{
    return deg*3.141592/180;
}
```

The calling code could be for example:

```
long double d = 45_deg;
```

As far as using `template <char...> double operator "" _π();` Maybe take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097767/user-defined-literals-for-variadic-char-templatehttp://)

Comment: I did look at the examples in the link but I did not understand what the difference was in the two `_Z` operators, if the `_Z` was not reserved then how would you call it?  Would that also be a user defined literal?  What does the extra space mean?  Also the `_π` part was left unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think i am being clear in my question.  What I meant to ask about the difference between the two `_Z` things was what exactly the space meant?  I know how to call the operator in the usual case, but what does the space mean?  Is it always an error?

Comment: @Curious - If you read the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) close enough it explains that `""_Z` (without a space) is ok, even though `_Z` is reserved. It also shows that the even more controversial  `complex<float>` literal `""if` (again no space) must work, even though `if` is a keyword.

Comment: "Basically: operator""_Z && operator"" _Z are two different identifiers and the latter is reserved." -- Huh? No, this is totally wrong. operator""_Z and operator"" _Z, if valid, would be the exact same function. Try it yourself with that operator"" _deg: add an operator""_deg and see if you get a redefinition error. The problem with operator"" _Z is that because _Z is reserved for implementation use, the implementation could e.g. define it as a macro expanding to anything you like. operator""_Z avoids that problem because _Z is not a separate token there, it's part of the ""_Z token.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was going of the top of my head and was mistaken.

Comment: `_π(char...c)` and `double d = 'c'_π;` -- Sorry, but this is clearly just guessing, and you've guessed badly.

Comment: I wont deny it, it was just a guess. I hadn't seen that one before.